# Switch between fragments from inside one of the fragmens

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments

Two days ago i asked the following question: 
[Change the fragment in a framelayout from within another fragment of said framelayout](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48345030/9240886)

A fellow user Krish, really helped me out in finding out what was wrong with the way i thought, but i am stil not sure how to actually get what i want done.

I want to be able to switch between three fragments in one FrameLayout. 
- the first of the three is loaded at the start of the parent fragment and when back is pressed at the second fragment
- the second must be replacing the first at the click of an item in the listview of the first fragment, and when the back button is pressed from the third fragment
-the third must be loaded when a button is pressed in the second layout

I've tried achieving this by calling the following line whenever the fragment must be changed. A1_frame is the FrameLayout of the parent Fragment/Layout and A1_B0_C2 is the fragment i am replacing

```
getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.A1_Frame, new A1_B0_C2()).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

From what i understand the problem with my solution is that it isn't possible to replace a fragment in the FrameLayout of a parent Fragment/Layout, but if it would work, it would solve my solution. thats why i chose to put it in here.

I hope someone is able to tell me what would work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`getChildFragmentManager()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getChildFragmentManager()) returns the Fragment manager of the Fragment it's being called from, in this case whatever Fragment is in A1_Frame

The method you're looking for is [`getFragmentManager()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getFragmentManager()), which returns the Fragment Manager of the Activity/Fragment that the Fragment is a part of. I.e. MainActivity, or whatever is creating your first fragment.

Comment: The reactions krish posted make more sense now! Thank you very much my application is finally running smooth!